# Expected X-Requested-With header' python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

So I've been trying to use requests so I can log in to replit.com to access files from my account and pull them to me, however on the log in part it says 'Expected X-Requested-With header', and for the status code it keeps giving me 403 (I think that means forbidden). Also to mention that requests.get() works completely fine, however the method I use has to be for a field where the method is POST.  I tried to see the HTML response, however I think there is only the Expected X-Requested With header. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? (down below)

```
response = requests.post("https://replit.com/login", auth = (email, password), allow_redirects = True)
```

Also even if the requests.post is only the URL it still doesn't work. Any help?

Edit:
I figured out how to do the headers, it turned out the website had its own header so I used that, but now I can't bypass recaptcha.

Comment: Try out this - 
headers = dict()
headers['X-Requested-With'] = "XMLHttpRequest"
response = requests.post("https://replit.com/login", auth = (email, password), allow_redirects = True)

Comment: @Smaurya I tried that and it mostly worked, but it returned "requires referer, referrer, or origin header." And I added one, 'https://www.google.com/', the one my browser sends. But it said invalid referrer, with two Rs. So far I can't figure out what is a referrer in HTTP, I know referer is a misspelling of referrer, but instead of one R it used two. Is this intentional, or is it simply https://google.com/? (I also used Referer to see if it was a problem with the capitalization, however this still doesn't work.)